What is the difference between Stop-Service and ServiceController.Stop()?
In PowerShell, when I use Stop-Service to stop a Windows service, if the service gets stuck in the “Stopping” state, Stop-Service will hang indefinitely.
When I use ServiceController.Stop() method and the service is stuck in a “Stopping” state, it looks to continue past the line and go to the ServiceController.WaitForStatus() function.
The Microsoft docs don’t seem to go heavily into detail with descriptions. Stop-Service and the Stop() function are both using ServiceController.
So does Stop-Service wait for the service to return a stop status so using WaitForStatus with it is redundant? And the Stop() just sends a stop command but does not know the outcome?
What is the difference between these two methods and where might one use one over the other?

Stop-Service is a cmdlet, not a method. Cmdlets are usually task-oriented, and comes with the bells and whistles necessary to interact with PowerShell pipelines. Internally it calls ServiceController.Stop() and optionally ServiceController.WaitForStatus()

ServiceController is a .Net class where as Stop-Service is a PowerShell CmdLet, that wraps some of ServiceController's functionality to make it easier to use in PowerShell. For example Stop-Service will interact with the PowerShell pipeline.
ServiceController.Stop() only tells the service and its dependencies to stop, it does not wait for them to stop. As you say you can wait for the service to stop by using ServiceController.WaitForStatus(Stopped).
Stop-Service calls ServiceController.Stop() and ServiceController.WaitForStatus(Stopped) for you. As such it blocks until the service has finished stopping. If you don't want to wait use Stop-Service -NoWait.
Basically when using PowerShell always use Stop-Service as ServiceController would be considered a lower level API.
